# Tags changing automatically on iOS build!

Tags: unity

First let me tell you that game runs fine in the editor. I check for hitting an enemy via a tag comparison and as I said it works correctly in the editor but when I deploy to my iPad and attach remotely with with MonoDevelop, I can see that the same object I'm checking against in Editor and had "Enemy" tag now has another tag, "Door".

Even before character doing anything, their tag is changed to "Door".

It's actually in the main menu and before running much code so I'm fairy certain it's not my code.

I'm sure there is nowhere in the code that I'm changing the tags.

And my specs: Unity is 5.6.1, Xcode is 8.3.3 and my iPad iOS is 10.3.2 and my macOS (OS X) is 10.12.5
(Tried with both Append and Replace builds)

Thanks